# How to add Context menu to a folder containing a specific type of file in Vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, contextmenu, vscode-extensions, right-click

I'd like to add a context menu in the Vscode explorer window as part of my extension development. it should appear when right-clicking on a folder containing build files. The menu action should only be enabled if the folder contains any type of build files, such as pom.xml or build.gradle.

```
export async function hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle(): Promise<boolean> {
    const workspaceFolders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;

    if (!workspaceFolders) {
        // No workspace folders found
        return false;
    }

    let hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle = false;

    // Iterate through each workspace folder
    for (const folder of workspaceFolders) {
        const folderPath = folder.uri.fsPath;

        // Check if either pom.xml or build.gradle exists in the folder
        const pomXmlPath = path.join(folderPath, 'pom.xml');
        const buildGradlePath = path.join(folderPath, 'build.gradle');

        if (fs.existsSync(pomXmlPath) || fs.existsSync(buildGradlePath)) {
            // Found either pom.xml or build.gradle
            hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle;
}

"menus": {
            "explorer/context": [
                {
                    "command": "dev.add.project",
                    "when": "myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle"
                },
```

I have called this function from extension.ts  file, which is specified in the main: field in pacakge.json file.

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle', devCommands.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle());
```

But the items are not displayed in the context menu even though the value is set true.

Comment: when do you execute this code, VSC is not calling code when it constructs the context menu, the context variable must already be set, but you don't know on which directory the context is called

Comment: why don't you just `return hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle;` at the end of the code

Comment: I have made the code little more clear. I have called the hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle() function from extension.ts file. @rioV8

Comment: when do you call the function

Comment: there is a `dev` command that dumps the current context vars to the dev-console, then you can see if the var is defined and what its value is

Comment: It appears that the registration of 'myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle' might not have been executed correctly in the extension.ts file using the specified command.


**context.subscriptions.push(
       vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle', () => devCommands.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle()),
    )**

Could you inform me if there are any extra configurations needed when registering a command in Visual Studio Code? @rioV8

Comment: you have defined a command that you can find in Command Palette, not the place you want, just call `devCommands.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle()` in the `activate` function

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have called devCommands.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle() in the activate function as mentioned. - `vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext','myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle', devCommands.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle()); `

Comment: what is the value of `myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle` **context variable**, you have the command `myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle` and the context variable `myExtension.hasPomXmlOrBuildGradle` they are DIFFERENT things with the same name

Comment: place a breakpoint in the function to see if it gets called, what is your `activation` property